# doing group on time column and summing up only unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with column `time, host, value`

The data is like below

```
time          host     value
14:00:00      inf1     5000
14:00:00      inf2     2000
14:01:00      inf1     5000
14:01:00      inf1     5000
14:01:00      inf2     2000
```

I want to group them by time which I am doing with the below code:-

```
df.set_index('time').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1Min')]).sum()
```

But I only want to sum the unique hosts and ignore any duplicate hosts. My desired output is

```
    time          sum     
    14:00:00      7000     
    14:01:00      7000
```

and not:-

```
time          sum     
14:00:00      7000     
14:01:00      12000
```

I want to ignore duplicate hosts during groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea is grouping by `Grouper` with `key='time'` and column `host` with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and then sum per second level:

```
df = (df.groupby(['host', pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1Min')])['value']
        .first()
        .sum(level=1)
        .reset_index(name='sum')
        )

print (df)
      time   sum
0 14:00:00  7000
1 14:01:00  7000
```

Another solution if there are only minutes times, so possible remove duplicates by `host` and `time`s by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['host','time'])
        .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1Min')])['value']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='sum'))

print (df)
      time   sum
0 14:00:00  7000
1 14:01:00  7000
```

---

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(subset=['host','time'])
        .groupby('time')['value']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='sum'))

print (df)
      time   sum
0 14:00:00  7000
1 14:01:00  7000
```

Solution with remove duplicates per groups is also possible, but slow if large data:

```
df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1Min')])
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[~x['host'].duplicated(), 'value'].sum())
        .reset_index(name='sum'))

print (df)
      time   sum
0 14:00:00  7000
1 14:01:00  7000
```

Comment: I think syntax wise, it may be more readable to remove duplicates first then sum; thus, avoiding the use of `apply`, ie `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['host', 'time']).groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1Min')]).sum()`

Comment: @GeneBurinsky - also is necessary remove dupes by `time`, edited answer. thank you.

Comment: @jezrael the answer which you originally posted, anythign wrong with that becaus eitw workign for me...df = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1Min')])
        .apply(lambda x: x.loc[~x['host'].duplicated(), 'value'].sum())
        .reset_index(name='sum'))

Comment: @abhi - there is nothing wrong, only slowier like another answers. Added to answer.

Comment: @jezrael thanks a lot for clarifying that as I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @jezrael can you please help me with this question:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568502/calculating-total-age-of-a-values-based-on-time-column