# Calculating total age of a values based on time column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, lambda

I have a DataFrame with columns:-

```
Time                   channel-id     user-id   call-id   call-duration
2020-06-25 00:06:22    abc            dg33      3532      30
2020-06-25 00:06:34    dfd            sd24      2342      35
2020-06-25 00:07:23    abs            gf22      5467      40
2020-06-25 00:07:44    abc            sd33      9233      42
2020-06-25 00:07:23    dfd            sd24      4938      2
2020-06-25 00:08:44    abs            hg34      2933      55
2020-06-25 00:08:43    abc            lk33      2933      43
2020-06-25 00:08:00    dfd            sd11      4532      56
2020-06-25 00:09:11    abc            lf33      2283      76
2020-06-25 00:09:12    abc            df43      4466      23
2020-06-25 00:09:55    abc            cv45      8888      12
```

I want to calculate the life-span of the channel like channel `abc` started at `2020-06-25 00:06:22` but in the channel `abc` the last user joined at `2020-06-25 00:09:55`.

I want to list all the channels with the channel life duration of each channel.

```
channel-id  channel-life-duration
abc         5 minutes
xyz         300 minutes
```

I have mentioned 5 minutes and 300 minutes just to give an idea of the format.

Also, if possible I also want to count total and unique user-id and call-id.

```
channel-id  channel-life-duration   Total-user-id  Tot-unique-user-id  Total-call-id  tot-unique-call-id
abc         5 minutes                10             6                   11             10       
xyz         300 minutes              11             7                   12             9
```

I want to scale this to millions of rows so, how I can make the computation fast.

Comment: @jezrael can you please help!

Comment: Can you explain how you got 5min in the duration for `abc`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I didn't get! I am saying i want to get the same way. 5 minutes i  just ahve mentioned to give an idea for the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `channel-id`, then use `.agg` to aggregate the grouped dataframe according to the requirements:

```
df1 = (
    df.groupby('channel-id').agg(
        first=('Time', 'first'), last=('Time', 'last'),
        user_id=('user-id', 'count'), unique_user_id=('user-id', 'nunique'),
        call_id=('call-id', 'count'), unique_call_id=('call-id', 'nunique'),
        call_duration=('call-duration', 'last'))
    .add_prefix('total_')
    .rename(columns={'total_last': 'channel_life_duration'})
)

# Calculate the lifespan of the channel
df1['channel_life_duration'] = (
    df1['channel_life_duration'].sub(df1.pop('total_first'))
    .add(pd.to_timedelta(df1.pop('total_call_duration'), unit='s'))
    .div(np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

            channel_life_duration  total_user_id  total_unique_user_id  total_call_id  total_unique_call_id
channel-id                                                                                                 
abc                      3.750000              6                     6              6                     6
abs                      2.266667              2                     2              2                     2
dfd                      2.366667              3                     2              3                     3
```

Comment: its giving me typeerror :- TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
@shubham

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: '0.23.4' but what it had to do with version of pandas

Comment: Named aggregation is only supported above pandas version `0.25`.

Comment: i will upgrade and try

Comment: It's working now! it's giving me all the correct results but not the channel_life_duration.

Comment: Just to be clear, Can you explain the logic of calculating `channel_life_duration`?

Comment: Yes, support at 9:01 I started a game and created a channel and users are joining and leaving the channel till 9:10 and at 9:10 the channel got destroyed. so the duration is 9 minutes and I apologize for my previous comment its giving me the correct result.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! one question? Is it scalabel, I mean if i will use it on say billions of records then any suggestion to makke it fast or its fine?

Comment: I guess it should be fine, because we have utilized vectorized universal function in doing all the calculations.

Comment: Hey @shubham... So, is there a way if I can add the last value of column duration into the channel_life duration. So, Let's say for abc you got 3.550000 minutes but I want to add the last value of duration which is 12 (seconds) here.

Comment: Yep you can do that.

Comment: Yes, I am trying but can you please give some hint. @Shubham

Comment: @abhi Sure. I have edited the answer which now gives you the new desired result.